# Does REST breaks data encapsulation?

Tags: api, oop, rest

I am trying to understand the scope and limits of RESTful APIs. My specific question is this: How can I handle with REST an API that exposes operations rather than resources? Should I give up to the temptation of exposing operations and rethink the API to expose data (resources). Coming from OOP that feels like a blatant violation of object encapsulation.

Imagine that you need to expose a REST API that does a money transfer: transfers an amount from one account into another account. If I understand REST, the two accounts should be exposed as resources and two different UPDATE operations would have to be invoked on these two resources. To me, this feels like a clear violation of the data encapsulation. My tendency is to create an API that models the operation “transfer money” rather than the resource “account”. Can I create a REST API that does the “data transfer”? Is that no longer REST (since it does not appear to be resource centric).

Any comment on this scenarios where RPC calls look more appropriate than REST?

Thanks

Comment: In RESTful Service you just need to call a post method to transfer funds from.one account to other and pass all information in post body! I dont understand why you need two resources for a single transaction.

Comment: My tendency is to do what you are suggesting. I am learning REST and I am concerned that if I do what you suggest I am no longer implementing REST (which must be resource centric) but rather an RPC call masquerading as REST.

Comment: There is no rule that says that a Resource should map to an actual object in your system. You could have a composite Resource, or a Resource that represents the result of an operation.

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that a Transfer is itself a resource, with its own life-cycle. We can PUT a transfer resource to (in business terms) initiate a transfer. The transfer resource will refer to account resources; resources referring to other resources is RESTful.

We can GET the transfer resource in order to determine its state.

We can even POST updates to the resource should, for example, some piece of information be incomplete.

Comment: Yes, a resource can be essentially any coherent and meaningful concept that may be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your preferences. Defining your APIS in pure REST way or having some lenient is up to you.

REST standardized the way of defining the APIs for easy of maintaining.

For example in SOAP days if you have to **create/modify/delete** account there will be three different api definitions like **createAcct. updateAccount, deleteAccount**.

Now with REST you have to define just one **/accounts/** and it will be assumed that **GET, PUT, POST** and **DELTE** HTTP methods do the corresponding actions.

To answer your question in your case API can be defined in two ways

**1)** - **/accounts/1234/transfer/** or have post the json body *{to_account:1212,amount:1221}* as part of request. This is NOT A PURE REST way of doing it

. Because you are defining action as part of API.

**2)** - **/accounts/1234/transactions** - post json body *{type:transfer, to_account:1212, amount:1212}*- This is PURE REST way since transaction is kind of new resource you are going to create in your system.

For many rest apis out there there are exceptions from pure REST way. one of the example is ' 'resetpassword'. Try to hack into some of the apis out there using firebug you will get a general understanding

Comment: +1. In deed, alternative 2 makes much more sense. It is also easier when you have more than one type of transfer money between accounts, like deposits, paying orders, etc. because you don't embed this info on the URL.